# Position of custom Angular2 Tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I have made a custom TooltipDirective that adds a tooltip to a TooltipService on hover following [this](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/building-tooltips-for-angular2-396320fa938f) guide. A tooltip ContainerComponent displays a TooltipComponent for each tooltip in the TooltipService and passes the TooltipComponent the ElementRef of the directive. My challenge is positioning the TooltipComponent - right now the components are being created correctly but the TooltipComponent is never being displayed.

The TooltipComponent currently looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'unit-info-tooltip',
    templateUrl: 'Template.html',
    styles: [`
            .tooltip {
                z-index: 100;
                padding: 2px;
                border: 1px solid #DDD;
                color: #333;
                background-color: #FFF;
                position: absolute;
            }
            `]
})
export class UnitInfoTooltipComponent {

    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() ref: any;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }
}
```

And its template:

```
<div class="tooltip" [style.top.px]="ref.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top" [style.left.px]="ref.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left">
    <h3>Info</h3>
    <p>Title: {{title}}</p>
</div>
```

And the TooltipDirective:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[custom-tooltip]',
})
export class CustomTooltipDirective implements OnDestroy {

    @Input() tooltipTitle: string = '';
    private id: number;

    constructor(
        private tooltipService: TooltipService,
        private element: ElementRef
    ) { }

    @HostListener('mouseenter')
    onMouseEnter(): void {
        // Show tooltip
        this.id = Math.random();
        let newComponent = {
            id: this.id,
            ref: this.element,
            title: this.tooltipTitle
        };
        this.tooltipService.components.push(newComponent);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')
    onMouseLeave(): void {
        // Hide tooltip
        this.destroy();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Hide tooltip
        this.destroy();
    }

    destroy(): void {
        const idx = this.tooltipService.components.findIndex((t) => {
            return t.id === this.id;
        });

        this.tooltipService.components.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the TooltipComponent is not being displayed at the location specified by its [style.top.px], [style.left.px] attributes.

Comment: Have you looked at the DOM after the view inits?  Is the tooltip element even present in it?  Does it have top / left applied as injected styles, and they're just incorrect or hidden behind another element?  A bunch of different things come to mind, and when you say "TooltipComponent is never being displayed," to me, means that it's not initializing the component, rather than it actually being displayed, but out of view, or a z-index issue.

Comment: @JSess The component is being initialized as I can log the ref.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect() values from within the component, however when I inspect the view and hover over the element with the attached directive, I don't see the component being added to the DOM

Comment: looking closer, you don't have custom-tooltip directive added to the element that you'd like for the directive to be applied to.

Comment: but if you're saying that the div with the tooltip markup is not appearing in the DOM, then you have issues with loading the component itself, and has nothing to do with the style, or the directive.  That could be a bunch of things - did you maybe forget to use the *<unit-info-tooltip></unit-info-tooltip>* in a rendered component?